# How to get pkill on git bash

Tags: bash, git, windows-10, minecraft

**background**

years ago I made a Minecraft spigot server and found a bash script to turn it on, in the script, it has a restart function that makes use of pkill to kill the old server and start a new one, I tried using it on my new spigot server to find that bash doesn't contain pkill, any google search I use relating to "how to get pkill on git bash windows 10" doesn't give me anything useful, the script has the following in it, the file is a .sh if that matters:

```
# /bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms4G -Xmx6G -jar spigot-1.16.3.jar nogui
pkill -f "spigot" #Not really needed, just there in case of anything.
echo Its off..sleeping for 5
sleep 5
done
```

**My question is,**
what can I use to kill the process by name like pkill would, or could I somehow install pkill to just work?

any help is appreciated and I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the shell is to be executed in a Windows Git bash session, then you do have access to Windows commands, like [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill), in said bash session.
For example, in my bash session, I can type:

```sh
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git/gtarsum (master)
$ taskkill
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Neither /FI nor /PID nor /IM were specified.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.
```

In your case, a `taskkill /F /IM spigot` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I use the `Git bash` in combination with `PsTools`. So in my opinion you can do a lot of cool things with Windows, too. I will give an easy example. In Linux you can run `ps aux | grep spigot`. With your `Git bash` it is `ps aux -W | grep spigot`. If you would know the `<pid>` you could kill it by using the pid. In Linux this would be `kill -f <pid>`. With `Git bash` it is `kill -f -W <pid>`. So you need the `-W` argument to access processes running in Windows. The `Git bash` sadly does not support a `pkill` command. An alternative to `taskkill /F /IM spigot` could be using [PsKill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) from `PsTools`. You could simple run `PsKill -t spigot`.